# Random: An error was thrown in afterAll TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, karma-runner

From time to time karma for unexplained reasons, returns a difficult to debug error:

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at <Jasmine>
    at subscribeTo (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:28:1)
    at subscribeToResult (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:15:23)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:74:50)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:68:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:51:1)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:53:1)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js:38:1)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js:53:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:205:1)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:143:1)
```

Any of you have an idea how to track what it concerns?

Use:

```
Angular 9
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "karma-scss-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
```

Answer (score 5):

In `karma.conf.js` in your *plugins* add `require('karma-spec-reporter')` and in your *reporters* add `spec`. This should list every test as it succeeds / fails along with the error messages.

This should help you identify which of the tests throws this error.

In my case I saw the error even though no `afterAll` statements were in my unit tests file.

In my specific case, the error would occur while testing a method that was using `mergeMap` to combine, in sequence, two observables (output of one observable became the input of another observable) and later it all would `.pipe(map(...),map(...))`. The unit tests relied on a mock of a service which didn't handle the `pipe()`

Previously in my `service.mock.ts` I had:

```
get: jasmine.createSpy('get').and.returnValue({
  pipe: jasmine.createSpy('pipe'),
})
```

The error went away with:

```
get: jasmine.createSpy('get').and.returnValue({
  pipe: jasmine.createSpy('pipe').and.returnValue(of({})),
})
```

Comment: The advice with the spec-reporter was a very good one. I somehow missed out on that and searched for hours which file is causing this error...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I figured out that it is caused by a switchMap that did not return an observable in all cases.

A simple default return of EMPTY sufficed to fix the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).